# How to compare current row with the previous row and increment the Mode value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have CSV file:

```
Notation RFRange  PRIRange  PSRange   PDRange     

 AA100   1000  1.20793  1.20794  138.96   
 AA100   2000  1.20787  1.20788  119.61        
 CC200   2000  1.20770  1.20779  210.42     
 SS400   4000  1.20779  1.20789   77.51       
 BB200   1000  1.20789  1.20792   56.97
```

This is what i got:

```
Notation RFRange  PRIRange  PSRange   PDRange   Mode

 AA100   1000  1.20793  1.20794  138.96        Mode2
 AA100   2000  1.20787  1.20788  119.61        Mode2
 CC200   2000  1.20770  1.20779  210.42        Mode2
 SS400   4000  1.20779  1.20789   77.51        Mode2
 BB200   1000  1.20789  1.20792   56.97        Mode2
```

**What i want is:** **When current row doesn't match with the previous row then increment the Mode.How should i do that?**

```
Notation RFRange  PRIRange  PSRange   PDRange   Mode

 AA100   1000  1.20793  1.20794  138.96        Mode1
 AA100   2000  1.20787  1.20788  119.61        Mode2
 CC200   2000  1.20770  1.20779  210.42        Mode3
 SS400   4000  1.20779  1.20789   77.51        Mode4
 BB200   1000  1.20789  1.20792   56.97        Mode5
```

Code:

```
 df['Mode'] = np.where((df['Notation'] == df['Notation'].shift()) & ((df['RFRange'] == 

 df['RFRange'].shift()) & (df['PRIRange'] == df['PRIRange'].shift()) & (df['PDRange'] == 

 df['PDRange'].shift()) & (df['PSRange'] == df['PSRange'].shift())),"Mode1","Mode2")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use, [`df.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html), [`df.any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) & [`Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
c = df.ne(df.shift()).any(axis=1).cumsum()
df['Mode'] = 'Mode' + c.astype(str)
```

---

```
# print(df)
  Notation  RFRange  PRIRange  PSRange  PDRange   Mode
0    AA100     1000   1.20793  1.20794   138.96  Mode1
1    AA100     2000   1.20787  1.20788   119.61  Mode2
2    CC200     2000   1.20770  1.20779   210.42  Mode3
3    SS400     4000   1.20779  1.20789    77.51  Mode4
4    BB200     1000   1.20789  1.20792    56.97  Mode5
```

Comment: is there any away i check the rows on specific col. Ex if i want to check the previous rows on Notation PRIRange and PSRange columns then is this right? c = (df['Notation'], df['PRIRange'], df['PSRange']).ne(df['Notation'].shift() & df['PRIRange'].shift() & df['PSRange'].shift()).any(axis=1).cumsum()
d

Comment: Yes, you can do that just define the `cols` which you want to compare using `cols = ['Notation', 'PRIRange', 'PSRange']` then simply use `c = df[cols].ne(df[cols].shift()).any(axis=1).cumsum()`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I appreciate it.